# Does syncing work for calendar?

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-touch, calendar

Is it possible to sync the calendar on 18.04 desktop with the calendar on my Ubuntu Touch phone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only two currently supported methods of calendar syncing on Ubuntu Touch, are via Nextcloud, or Google Calendar. You can also sync your calendar on your PC running Ubuntu with either of these.